# How can I Use LINE Notify to send image only

Tags: python-3.x

How can I Use LINE Notify to send image only

my code below (it works when message and image were sent at the same time):

`def lineNotifyMessage(token, message, picurl):
      header = {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + token, 
          "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
      payload = {
          'message':message,
          'imageThumbnail':picurl,
          'imageFullsize':picurl
      }
      r = requests.post("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", headers = header, data = payload)
      return r.status_code`

---

but when I change code below, it doesn't work(actually I want to send the only image by LINE Notify):

`def lineNotifyMessage_photo(token, picurl):
      header = {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + token, 
          "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
      payload = {
          'imageThumbnail':picurl,
          'imageFullsize':picurl
      }
      r = requests.post("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", headers = header, data = payload)
      return r.status_code`

Comment: I'm not familiar with LINE but a quick glance at the [docs](https://notify-bot.line.me/doc/en/) shows `message` is a required parameter. Might an empty string or null achieve what you want?